# Paperclip - Validate File Type but not Presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip

I am using paperclip to handle my file uploads, and in one situation I don't want the file to be mandatory. I do however want to make sure it is a specific file type when it is present.

I have this:

```
class TestModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    #stuff
    has_attached_file :sound #etc...
    validates_attachment_content_type :sound, :content_type => ['audio/mp3', 'application/x-mp3']
end
```

And when I have no sound file present, it tells me it is not one of the valid content types. I've tried adding `''` to the `:content_type` array, which also doesn't work!

I also attempted creating a lambda procedure for the `:if` property, but I can't get it to run without some kind of error.

Anything missing here?

Comment: I asked as similar question a while back http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257041/smarter-paperclip-validations - I got it working with a proc.  maybe it will help you

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could try a 'conditional validation' where the condition is if a file is present?

```
class TestModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  #stuff
  has_attached_file :sound #etc...
  validates_attachment_content_type :sound, :content_type => ['audio/mp3', 'application/x-mp3'], :if => :sound_attached?

  def sound_attached?
    self.sound.file?
  end
end
```

Comment: I realised I had to do this after upgrading to Paperclip 2.3.2 from Paperclip 2.3.1.1

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in newer versions of paperclip (I think around 2.3.4 based on when the commit was made). See discussion at

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/125

Answer (score 0):

chunk of my model:

```
  has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :medium => ["300x300>", :png], :thumb => ["100x100>", :png] }
  validates_attachment_size :logo, :less_than => 2.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
```

and if I provide no image file, @obj.update_attributes(..) raises no error, but validates if I provide a file. Maybe you use older version of paperclip?

```
gem list | ack paperclip
paperclip (2.3.1.1)
```

Comment: I have version 2.3.2 and have the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

First let me say that I am new to both ruby and rails. Secondly, I don't know if this can be applied to audio files but with images I just set up a default image so that one way or another there is a photo associated with each record.

```
has_attached_file :photo, styles: { small: "64x64", med: "100x100", large: "200x200" }, default_url: "/images/no-image-available.png"
```