# Paperclip's content_type is invalid according to app, but isn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm new to Paperclip and it all seemed to work pretty fast. I'm trying to get the user to only upload PNG's or JPG's though, and although I'm uploading a JPG and my content_type validates for JPG it says it's invalid nonetheless.

I've tried removing the PNG content_type, to no avail.

I've tried using `has_attached_file` aswell, but it seems to ignore the :content_type and stuff. Because if I upload a JPG with `:content_type => "image/png"` only; It doesn
t give an error.

Any suggestions?

```
    validates_attachment :avatar, :styles => { 
                                    :medium => "300x300", 
                                    :thumb => "100x100" 
                                }, :content_type => { 
                                    :content_type => "image/jpg", 
                                    :content_type => "image/png"
                                },
                                :size => { :in => 0..1.megabytes }
```

Oh, and while I'm at it; I want to get my thumb and medium to the fixed width. So no scaling like 100x80 but just 100x100 either way. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're trying to use some `Paperclip validation`, which you could look at here: [Paperclip - Validate File Type but not Presence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807008/paperclip-validate-file-type-but-not-presence)

According to that answer, you could use this:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :sound, :content_type => ['audio/mp3', 'application/x-mp3'], :if => :sound_attached?
```

---

An alternative is to use `lambda` to check to see whether you're dealing with a specific content type. Here's an example from one of our live apps:

```
   has_attached_file :attachment,
            styles:          lambda { |a| a.instance.is_image? ? {:small => "x200>", :medium => "x300>", :large => "x400>"}  : {:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}, :medium => { :geometry => "300x300#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10}}}

    def is_image?
            attachment.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(image)
    end
```

Lambda is only really a way to gauge whether the `content-type` is what you need (I.E you only allow JPG images). In order to validate the presence of an image (rather than a video), you'd need to [`validates_attachment_content_type`](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Validators/HelperMethods#validates_attachment_content_type-instance_method)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've used your `validates_attachment_content_type` which at first didn't seem to work. adding `image/jpeg`(with an E!) to the content_types did the trick, though!

Comment: :) How did `E!` fix things? I've never seen that before!

Comment: image/jpg is something different from image/jpeg apparantly.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue tonight, and it turned out I needed image/jpeg and image/jpg

```
 validates_attachment :avatar, :styles => { 
                                    :medium => "300x300", 
                                    :thumb => "100x100" 
                                }, :content_type => { 
                                    :content_type => "image/jpg",
                                    :content_type => "image/jpeg", 
                                    :content_type => "image/png"
                                },
                                :size => { :in => 0..1.megabytes }
```

It worked when just trying /^image/ but I like being specific.

Answer (score 0):

I compared the log from server, and noticed the different on content-type header. It should be 'image/jpeg'

```
Parameters: {"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0055b7d4c30870 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170510-21515-11ld4ji.jpg>, @original_filename="IMAG0303.jpg", @content_type="multipart/form-data", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar\"; filename=\"IMAG0303.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data\r\nContent-Length: 1057779\r\n">}

Parameters: {"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0055b7d3ec3408 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170510-21515-1l0x8sw.jpg>, @original_filename="2017.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar\"; filename=\"photo_10/05/2017.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}
```